# toggle button state depend on feedback from server

Tags: java, android, server

Arduino server and android client i want to make toggle button state depend on string feedback from server

i have tried this but does not work

this code below was woeking week ago i didnt change anything but now i got the problem

Arduino:

```
if (packetBuffer[0]=='3')
{
    if (buttonstate == HIGH)
    {
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(),Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("on");
        Udp.endPacket();
    }
    else
    {

        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(),Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("off");
        Udp.endPacket();
    }

}
```

Android:

```
coming = new String(recd.getData());

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),coming,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(coming);

if (coming=="on")
{
    apf.setChecked(true);
}

else if (coming=="off")
{
    apf.setChecked(false);
}

d1.close();
```

Comment: Does application crashes? Post your Logcat.

Comment: no it does not but the toggle buttons not changing after receiving feedback